# How to ensure the foundation-apps _settings.scss file isn't overwritten when I run 'bower update foundation-apps'

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, bower, zurb-foundation-apps

I have installed Foundation for Apps via bower (`bower install foundation-apps`).

Foundation says to use the _settings.scss for customization. However, isn't this file overwritten when I eventually have to update to the latest version (`bower update foundation-apps`)?

Comment: Did you try running this command to see if it *actually* does what you think it does (and don't want it to do)?

Comment: Yes, I did. My edits of the _settings.scss in bower_components/foundation-apps/scss wasn't overwritten. But am assuming that because bower found nothing to update as I am on the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to copy the `_settings.scss` file out of the `bower_components` directory and into your project's `scss` folder so that it does not get overwritten when you update. It's the only file you need to do that with.

From the **[Foundation for Apps Sass Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/sass)**

> ### The Settings File
>
> All Foundatiion projects include a settings file, named _settings.scss. If you're using the CLI to create a Foundation for Apps project, you can find the settings file under client/assets/scss/. **If you're installing the framework standalone using Bower or npm, there's a settings file included in those packages, which you can move into your own Sass files to work with.**

Comment: How will foundation know to import this file?

Comment: You have to import it in your scss. Look at how the foundation apps template does it:  https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps-template/